# Fullcalendar json many sources

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar.js, which is Amazing by the way. On this occasion I discovered the manipulation of json datas.
My problem is the following : 
I have variables @missions and @events. But i cannot call and render both on my calendar. Can anyone help me on this ?

**what I have already tried**

1) add a second line with the good request  like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: '/missions.json',
  events: '/events.json'
})
```

2) Or add a second loop to my json file like this :

But none of this solution is working. Any ideas ?

```
json.array! @missions do |mission|
  date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
  json.id mission.id
  json.title mission.title
  json.start mission.start.strftime(date_format)
  json.end mission.end.strftime(date_format)
  json.edit_url edit_mission_path(mission)
end

json.array! @events do |event|
  date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
  json.id event.id
  json.title event.title
  json.start event.start.strftime(date_format)
  json.end event.end.strftime(date_format)
  json.edit_url edit_event_path(event)
end
```

But none of this solution is working. Any ideas ?

Comment: If you don't want to combine the data sources server-side, then use eventSources: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [ '/missions.json',
  '/events.json'
]);` https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventSources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one "events" key in your fullCalendar objects.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: '/events.json',
});
```

If you want them to both exist in the same calendar, either combine them in the controller or in JS. Combining them in the controller is likely far easier.

This is the rudimentary controller way of doing it:

```
def action
  @missions = Mission.all
  @events = Event.all
  @all_events = @events + @missions
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json:  @all_events }
    format.html
  end
end
```

If you want to use a jbuilder file, then perhaps it might look like this:

```
missions = json.array! @missions do |mission|
  date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
  json.id mission.id
  json.title mission.title
  json.start mission.start.strftime(date_format)
  json.end mission.end.strftime(date_format)
  json.edit_url edit_mission_path(mission)
end

events = json.array! @events do |event|
  date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
  json.id event.id
  json.title event.title
  json.start event.start.strftime(date_format)
  json.end event.end.strftime(date_format)
  json.edit_url edit_event_path(event)
end

events + missions
```

Notice the addition still occurs at the bottom. IMO, transformations are best left to helpers and controller actions whereas jbuilder kind of blends them into the views which just obfuscates. jbuilder should largely be used for rendering particular JSON. Not for mutating it, which we sort of do here.